# How to do php validation on form submit on the same page

Tags: php

I have a HTML form that asks the user to select the image to be uploaded

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="fileToUpload" name="fileToUpload" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
    <input type="submit" value="Save Recipe" name="submit">
</form>
```

In the beginning of the page I have a set of php code to check if the form was submitted

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  .... perform the upload image routine ...
  .... output the error message if any ...
}
```

My problem is that since the php snipped is executing at the top of the page the error message is also getting output at the top. Is there a smarter way to output this message at the bottom of the page other than using session variable?

Comment: Ouput the message inside of a <div>. Then using CSS, position it at the bottom of your page.

Comment: store the error[s] in an array and then if the error array is not empty loop through and output the errors any where you want in the page

Comment: you can show error message any where .just assign `$error="something"` and echo $error where you want

Comment: Sure, switch the codes around.

Comment: Thanks everyone this is resolved. Switching codes worked the best though there are some other design issues that I will have to take care of.

Comment: @coderatlarge no problemo

Comment: I almost popped my comment as an answer earlier ;-)

Answer (score 0):

switching codes worked. need to re-design the flow.

Comment: [Didn't I say that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44479773/how-to-do-php-validation-on-form-submit-on-the-same-page#comment75954398_44479773) LOL!